# regression analysis with both slope and value data

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, estimation, optimization

I have measured data $\{x_i, y_i, y'_i\}$, to which I would like to fit a polynomial $y=a x^2 + bx + c$ and $y' = 2ax + b$.

It occurs to me that the regression problem of fitting $y=a x^2 + bx +c$ to $\{x_i, y_i\}$ is typically solved by choosing $a,b,c$ that minimize $\sum_i(ax_i^2+bx_i+c-y_i)^2$, and fitting $y'=2ax+b$ to $\{x_i, y'_i\}$ would typically be solved by choosing $a,b$ that minimize $\sum_i(2ax_i+b-y'_i)^2$.  So that I could, perhaps, choose $a,b,c$ that minimize $\sum_i\alpha(ax_i^2+bx_i+c-y_i)^2 + (1-\alpha)(2ax_i+b-y'_i)^2$, (where $\alpha$ is a constant weighting factor), but I can't think of a principled way of choosing $\alpha$.  Presumably this problem has been studied before, but I don't know what it's called, and have been having trouble finding any relevant leads.

Comment: For your first model, why can't you use traditional regression with the variables $x_i$, $z_i=x_i^2$ as your independent variables?  Indeed, this has been extensively studies:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression

Comment: "traditional regression" is "minimize $\sum_i(ax_i^2+bx_i+c-y_i)^2$".  It doesn't take into account the slope information, $y'_i$.

Comment: This can be solved once you provide details of the measurement system.  Of importance are whether the errors in measuring $y_i$ and $y^\prime_i$ are dependent and if so, how.  (Long ago I solved this problem for spatial coordinates--where the $x_i$ and $y_i$ are vectors--in the case where either one or both of $y_i$ and $y^\prime_i$ are available.  The interest lay in extending the usual fitting techniques to cases where *only* the derivative $y^\prime$ is available but the value $y$ either is not or is so crudely measured that it's worthless. Could that be your kind of application?)

Comment: @WanderingLogic I see what you are asking now! Sorry - I didn't fully understand that you were trying to take into account the $ $y'$ until you elaborated in your comment.

Comment: The errors of measuring $y_i$ and $y'_i$ are dependent.  I'm pretty sure $y_i$ is more accurate.  $x_i$ is actually the (scalar) distance along a ray in a line search during a stochastic gradient descent problem.  $y_i$ is the (scalar) cost function, and $y'_i$ is actually the norm of the gradient (which is calculated using back propagation on the cost function).

Comment: It will therefore be important to describe that dependence as specifically and quantitatively as you can, because it will play an important role in the solution.

Comment: If the y' values ultimately derive from the actual y values (if indirectly), do they actually add any information at all?